# Subcategory filter showing (0) products even though there are many products

Tags: category, filtered-nav

My subcategory filter in the sidebar shows that there are 0 products in some of the categories but then you click on them and there are loads of products in them. 
This only happens with some of the categories though.
Check out this link to see what I mean.
https://realboysrealtoys.co.uk/accessories.html

Comment: Did you rebuild your indexes? Also, do you have a custom module installed? By default the filter by category does not take you to the subcategory page. You should see in the url `accessories.phtml?cat=10`

Answer (score 1):

Log into the admin area, hover over catalog and select Manage Categories. First thing to check is that you have the correct Store View selected in the upper-left corner of the categories page. Next, you need to make sure that all of your categories that have sub-categories are set to "Yes" for the "Is Anchor" field in the Display Settings tab. Then products that you add to the sub-categories will automatically be added to the main categories. There is a section about "Is Anchor" here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-and-managing-categories

Answer (score 1):

Just refresh your cache (System > Cache Management > Flush Management Cache